# Is it possible to generically access an enum value in Rust?

Tags: rust

I have an enum like this:

```
enum MyEnum {
    Variant1(u8),
    Variant2(u8),
    Variant3(u8),
    Variant4(u8),
}
```

And I have an array of enums:

```
let my_enums = [
    MyEnum::Variant1(2),
    MyEnum::Variant3(5),
    MyEnum::Variant2(40),
    ...
];
```

Now I want to check that none of the values are above some max limit.
The only choices I'm aware of are:

```
for e in &my_enums {
    match e {
        MyEnum::Variant1(v) => if *v > MAX_VALUE {},
        MyEnum::Variant2(v) => if *v > MAX_VALUE {},
        MyEnum::Variant3(v) => if *v > MAX_VALUE {},
        MyEnum::Variant4(v) => if *v > MAX_VALUE {},
    }
}
```

OR

```
for e in &my_enums {
    match e {
        MyEnum::Variant1(v) |
        MyEnum::Variant2(v) |
        MyEnum::Variant3(v) |
        MyEnum::Variant4(v) => if *v > MAX_VALUE {},
    }
}
```

And apparently you can make a macro that handles this.
Are those the only options? There's no simple way to match all variants with a single u8 without listing them individually?

Comment: @PeterHall Why was this closed? That questions is very different.

Comment: @IbraheemAhmed I chose the wrong duplicate first time. The two answers that I replaced that with should answer your question.

Comment: Enums were designed to be heterogeneous types, there is no built-in shorthand for cases where they all just happen to be the same.

Comment: If you have many variants with the same type inside, maybe it's better to create a struct containing separately `u8` and `MyEnum`, and remove all `u8` from variants